# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE No Module Named

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-settings

I am trying to create a population script for my database, but I get a No module named error.

```
Project Structure:
staticone/
    manage.py
    mysite/
      populate_rango
      settings
      urls
      __init__
      wsgi
      rango/
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "populate_rango.py", line 8, in <module>
django.setup()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

My path:

```
 ['/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/staticone/mysite', 
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-
 x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

My settings.py file is under mysite

populate_rango.py under mysite folder:

```
 import sys
 print (sys.path)
 import os
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','settings')
 import django
 django.setup()
 from mysite.rango.models import Category,Page
```

If I try

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','mysite.settings')`

I get the same error:

> No module named mysite.

mysite is on the path, so I am confused as to why it is not finding the settings file.

Comment: Is `mysite` in `INSTALLED_APPS` (`settings.py`) ?

Comment: Yes, I have mysite in INSTALLED_APPS under settings.py

Comment: Please show the layout of your project, in particular where `populate_rango.py` is compared to your `manage.py` and `settings.py` files.

Answer (score 10):

I needed to put the parent directory of mysite on the path. I only had `/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/staticone/mysite`.  Now it works when I included 
`/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/staticone/`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/virtenv/webstatic/staticone/")
print (sys.path)
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','mysite.settings')
import django
django.setup()
from mysite.rango.models import Category,Page
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it dynamic by

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.__str__())
print (sys.path)
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','mysite.settings')
import django
django.setup()
from mysite.rango.models import Category,Page
```